# How to do if first.row in SQL

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I need to download a bunch a of data from an Oracle database using SAS EG. In order to do that I need to convert the following code into Oracle SQL. Can someone please help?

```
Data have;
Infile datalines delimiter=',';
Input A $ B C;
Datalines;
abc123,5,1
abc123,5,2
abc123,5,3
abc123,10,4
abc123,10,5
abc123,10,6
abc123,20,7
;
Run;

Proc sort data=have;
By a b c;
Run;

Data want;
Set have;
By A B;
If first.B;
Run;
```

Comment: What happens if you use Oracle passthrough in the data step using your logic? Will it bring the entire table to SAS and then do the filtering? If you want to check this, get only a few rows add the following option: `options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog;`

Comment: Are they variables other than A, B and C in the actual dataset you are creating?  If so then include one in your example data.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have those three variables it is easy.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
    select distinct a,b,c
    from have
    group by a,b
    having c=min(c)
  ;
quit;
```

Results:

```
Obs      A        B    C

 1     abc123     5    1
 2     abc123    10    4
 3     abc123    20    7
```

Comment: I don't think this would work in passthrough to Oracle, would it?

Comment: @Joe Do you mean will SAS be able to convert that query into SQL to run in the database  via implicit passthru?  Not sure.

Comment: No; I mean that sql isn’t valid in oracle. The group by doesn’t have c in it so it’s not legal. Only SAS would allow that.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is just what Stu said; test out doing this in passthrough.

```
libname oralib oracle [connection options];
options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog;

Data want;
 Set oralib.have;
 By A B;
 If first.B;
Run;
```

Directly that, and see if it works the way you want.  It might do what you need.  You don't need a `proc sort`, the sorting will happen in the database.

However, if it doesn't, and I suspect it won't actually pass through the whole thing since that's not directly supported I don't think, you can do it in SQL pass through.

Here's the base SAS code equivalent:

```
proc sql;
  select distinct country, region, actual
  from sashelp.prdsale main
  where actual = (
    select min(actual) 
    from sashelp.prdsale sub
    where sub.country = main.country
      and sub.region  = main.region
  );
quit;
```

That is oracle-compatible code, you'd just need to substitute the actual table/variables and wrap it in pass through, ie

```
proc sql;
  connect to oracle [connection options];
  select * from connection to oracle (
     ... your query here ...


  );
quit;
```

The `distinct` isn't needed if you know it will return only one row per record without it, by the way.